Can supersonic flow be achieved without converging diverging nozzle?
Can supersonic flow be achieved without the presence of a converging diverging nozzle if sufficient pressure difference is available?
https://www.tomshardware.com/desktops/pc-building/an-ordinary-squirt-of-canned-air-achieves-supersonic-speeds-engineer-spots-telltale-shock-diamonds
The article above mentions that 'shock diamonds' can be seen out of a flow coming out of compressed air can at 70 PSI. I am assuming that the flow must have reached supersonic for the shock diamonds to occur.

I would be astonished if an ordinary can of compressed air produced supersonic flow. They don't hurt you when you put your finger in front of them.

I once did a laboratory exercise taking schleiren photos of an air duster can just like this, and it was laminar outflow that transitioned to turbulent. But I'm not saying shocks cannot happen with the right conditions. 70-90 psi is plenty high enough to cause a shock across a thin orifice.  Maybe it only happened in the first instant when the pressure was at max

I am not sure if it is a shock, but if you rapidly puncture a very large tractor tire it sounds like a strong chemical explosion and there is a condensation cloud.  Suppose it is a shock, would this qualify as a converging-diverging nozzle for your criteria?

@honeste_viviere Achieving supersonic flow is possible without converging diverging duct (eg. a supersonic aircraft). What I intended to ask was that is it possible to achieve supersonic speed in a duct without presence of a properly designed converging diverging nozzle, as is the case in the compressed air nozzle? From what I could gather, it is not possible to achieve supersonic speeds in a closed duct without a CD nozzle.

@Johnsmith - Sorry, I didn't see this comment until just now.  Okay, suppose you have an infinitely strong tube and within the tube you have a piston.  If you apply enough energy, fast enough to the piston, you will get a shock wave.
